# Can't parse string with simple xml

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I have pretty simple xml like this:

```
<EncryptedToken>11d8575638eaa52b</EncryptedToken>
```

Here is my java class for it:

```
@Root
public class EncryptedTokenDto {
@Element(name = "EncryptedToken", required = false)
private String encryptedToken;

public String getEncryptedToken() {
    return encryptedToken;
}

public void setEncryptedToken(String encryptedToken) {
    this.encryptedToken = encryptedToken;
}
```

}

But when I try to parse this xml `encryptedToken` is always `null`. What is wrong with my code?

**UPDATE:** 
 
Here is my sample code from `main`:

```
   Serializer serializer = new Persister();

    EncryptedTokenDto encryptedTokenDto = null;
    try {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n <EncryptedToken>11d8575638eaa52b</EncryptedToken>";
        encryptedTokenDto = serializer.read(EncryptedTokenDto.class, xml);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (encryptedTokenDto != null) {
        System.out.println(encryptedTokenDto.getEncryptedToken());
    }
```

Actually it's not real code, because I receive xml from web service, but everything else works good, question is only in xml parsing.

**UPDATE 2:** 
 
I've found that if I change my xml like this:

```
String xml = "<root> \n <EncryptedToken>11d8575638eaa52b</EncryptedToken> \n </root>";
```

And write class like this:

```
@Root
public class EncryptedTokenDto {
@Element(name = "EncryptedToken", required = false)
private String encryptedToken;

public String getEncryptedToken() {
    return this.encryptedToken;
}

public void setEncryptedToken(String encryptedToken) {
    this.encryptedToken = encryptedToken;
}
}
```

Everyrthing is ok. 


**So my question is:** how is it possible to parse xml document without root relement using SimpleXml 
Note: I need to use SimpleXml, I can't use any other parser.

Comment: Try using different variable names and you'll eventually find it. Something like `encryptedToken`, `encryptedToken1`, `encryptedToken2` etc. The problem might be in `return encryptedToken;`, may be try changing it to `return super.encryptedToken;` or `return this.encryptedToken;`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try @Text, instead of @Element, it will work then